# FFMPEG: embed current time in milliseconds into video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I would like to embed the computer's local time ***in milliseconds*** into a stream using FFMPEG.

I can embed the local time in seconds using drawtext like so:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -vf "drawtext=text='%{localtime\:%T}'" -f flv <output>
```

Looking through the documentation for drawtext, doing some tests, and Googling around, it seems like `localtime` and `gmtime` don't provide milliseconds -- just seconds. However the `pts` options ***does*** have milliseconds:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -vf "drawtext=text='%{pts\:hms}'" -f flv <output>
```

I also found out that `pts` supports an offset, so I was able to use something like this to display local time (kind of):

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -vf "drawtext=text='%{pts\:hms\:$(date +%s.%N)}'" -f flv <output>
```

This had two problems:

1. It displayed something like `17499:17:29` for the time... I found a (rather complex) way to work around this
2. It uses the server's current time **when you first run the ffmpeg command** as the offset -- not the server's current time when ffmpeg actually starts decoding video. I noticed ffmpeg had about a 2-second startup time, causing the clock to be off by roughly 2 seconds

Is there a way to modify my solution, or an entirely separate solution, that can embed server local time in milliseconds into the stream?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input
       -vf "settb=AVTB,
            setpts='trunc(PTS/1K)*1K+st(1,trunc(RTCTIME/1K))-1K*trunc(ld(1)/1K)',
            drawtext=text='%{localtime}.%{eif\:1M*t-1K*trunc(t*1K)\:d}'"
       -f flv out
```

First, the incoming timestamps are represented as microsecond precision by forcing the timebase to the default AVTB which is `10e-6`.

Second, a new PTS is set, which comprises of the original PTS reduced to milliseconds and left-shifted (decimally) three digits. To this, is added the wallclock's milliseconds component. RTCTIME is available in setpts and returns an integer with microsecond precision.

Third, the text string has three parts. The first is the localtime which is formatted as a Y-M-D-H-M-S string and returns second precision. Then a dot to demarcate the milliseconds. In the third, `t` returns fractional seconds. The millisecond component is extracted and printed as an integer.

Comment: I'll have to read up on the `st` and `ld` functions you used, as well as the `eif` text expansion for drawtext, because I have no idea how this works :) But it works!

Comment: fix drawtext=text='%{localtime}.%{eif\:1M*t-1K*trunc(t*1K)\:d}'" to drawtext=text='%{localtime}.%{eif\:1M*t-1K*trunc(t*1K)\:d\:3}'" display correctly up to three decimal places.

Comment: @nico_lab thanks for the fix! but note: the formating has eaten some `*`.. fixed with code formating: `text='%{localtime}.%{eif\:1M*t-1K*trunc(t*1K)\:d\:3}'`

Comment: This seems to do nothing on macos with ffmpeg 6.0.

Comment: Nevermind, the timestamp was just  not visible black on black. One can change the positions with `x` and `y`. `drawtext=text='%{localtime}.%{eif\:1M*t-1K*trunc(t*1K)\:d}':x=100:y=100:fontsize=20`

Comment: @Gyan Is there a way I can set a specific date and time (including milliseconds) as the start of the text sequence?

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that FFMPEG supports an extended format string "%[1-6]N" which prints fractions of the second now:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Text-expansion

We can simply run this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf "drawtext='text=%{localtime\:%X.%N}:fontfile=c\:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf:fontsize=32:fontcolor=black'" output.mkv
```

Comment: For anyone who has access to the newest version of FFMPEG, this is a better solution than the somewhat hack-y (but very effective) answer provided by @Gyan

Answer (score 0):

based on gyan answer, i would like to have the millis component included in the start position. but if i try to "extend" the epoch to include the millis component i get no dratext

so--`gmtime\:'165261638830'\` doesnt work
but `gmtime\:'1652616388'\` , does

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 
    -i Jose.wav 
    -c:v ffv1 
    -c:a aac 
    -vf "transpose=1,
    settb=AVTB,
    setpts='trunc(PTS/1K)*1K+st(1,trunc(RTCTIME/1K))-1K*trunc(ld(1)/1K)',
    drawtext='
        fontfile=c\:/Windows/Fonts/courbd.ttf:
        fontsize=36:
        fontcolor=red:
        text=%{pts\:
            gmtime\:
            '165261638830'\}.%{eif\:
                1M*t-1K*trunc(t*1K)\:
                d}'" 
    output.mkv
```