# programmatically access the timestamp while screen capturing video on mac

Tags: macos, video-capture, screen-capture, video-editing

I am using Mac's screen capture functionality (cmd-shift-5 or screencapture at the terminal) to record audio/video screen recordings.

I would like to align some real world events for which I have timestamps to the video during editing. So, I would like to capture the timestamp of the screen recording (e.g. 0:01 after the first second of recording) and associate it with the real time at which it occurred. This way I can calculate the video timestamp at which the real world events occurred and make edits accordingly.

One idea I have for doing this is using cmd-shift-6 to take a screen shot of the touchbar on the Mac laptop, since the touchbar has the timestamp shown on it. I could then record the real time of the screenshot and use OCR to get the recording timestamp from the screenshot. However, using OCR seems unnecessarily complex and the timestamp in the touchbar screenshot is only accurate to a full second, and I would like more precision.

A second idea is to use the timestamp in the filename from the video. However, the timestamp in the filename is actually about 3 seconds earlier than the time at which the video starts, because it takes some time to start the recording. Since I want sub 1s precision, this isn't good enough either. It's possible that the 3 second recording start-up delay will be consistent enough that I can just add ~3 seconds to the timestamp from the video filename, but this seems likely to break if ever the start-up delay isn't precisely the same, and I expect the start-up delay will indeed change over time.

A third idea I have is to emit an audio watermark at some point during the recording at a known time. Then I can identify this watermark in the video to get the alignment between recording timestamps and real world time. This idea seems likely to work, but if there's something simpler I would of course prefer that.

So, is there a way to programmatically access an ongoing recording's timestamp while screen capturing video on mac?

Comment: Are you capturing the whole screen or just a part? Maybe you could display a clock and capture that to get synced before your actual recording starts and then edit that out once you have the time offset.

Comment: This may help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/47551016/2836621

Comment: @Mark, I have an external monitor and my laptop, and I'm screen capturing just the external monitor. Yes, I think that clock idea would work, and is better than the cmd-shift-6 idea :). Would still need to decide how to get the time back from the clock (OCR?), but that's definitely doable.

That link is interesting, but unfortunately I don't think it's immediately useful.

Comment: Unless -- is there a way to point ffmpeg at the screen capture as a stream while it's recording? -- because if that were the case then that link becomes useful. I don't know of a way to do that though.

Comment: I was suggesting/imagining you use `ffmpeg` itself to capture the screen.

Comment: I realized 10 minutes ago that must have been what you meant and came here to say so. Thanks for clarifying. Great idea.