# FFmpeg to create a custom time stamp with suffix (mins, hrs, days) and user defined time between frames

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp, imagej

I am looking to use FFmpeg (or something similar) to overlay a time stamp on videos.

I want it to have similar functionality to the timestamper plugin from ImageJ (I can't use ImageJ for this as it does not allow for large video files).

I'd like to be able to enter a starting time, a time between frames and a suffix. My video is made up of an image taken every 10 minutes for 20 days and I want to overlay the day as the video is playing. So for this, I'd like frames 1-144 (144 images per day) have 0 days in the corner of the video, frames 145-289 to have 1 days in the corner, and so on.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/66221082/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/47543426/ for a starting point.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? It seems I should try using the drawtext function but I still don't know how to do the things I mentioned above